# Responsive class setting iFrame height to 0, resulting in no image displayed

Tags: iframe, tumblr, responsive, responsiveness, tumblr-themes

While working on a project, I discovered some of my images on Tumblr are not displaying. The only clue I've found is that within the responsive-level-1 class (see below for html code), the height of the iFrame is set to 0. If I pop open a dev console in Chrome and set that to be, e.g., 1632 (not 0), the image appears. I'm using a theme (Brick theme/theme garden) , but am able to edit the html and css. Can I modify my css and/or HTML to fix this? The issue occurs across device platforms (desktop/phone/tablet).

Example of no image displayed- http://deligrossery.com/post/149661412746/gawad-deli-grocery-207-hart-st-brooklyn-ny

corresponding css files:
responsive.css: http://static.tumblr.com/eftyn9y/kc0og8vio/responsive.css
style.css: static.tumblr.com/3zmswwt/Fmkmwgp8e/style.css
(^ I can't post more than 2 links until my reputation is at least 10/add an https:// to the style.css).

`<iframe id="photoset_iframe_149661412746" class="photoset" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="0" width="500" style="border:0px; background-color:transparent; overflow:hidden;" src="http://deligrossery.com/post/149661412746/photoset_iframe/deligrossery/tumblr_ocn1e9dTfK1txl3g8/500/false" name="photoset_iframe_149661412746"></iframe>`

Comment: In the css try adding: `.photoset { height:initial };` are you working on this now though, as currently for me the photoset post is not showing in an iframe?

Comment: Hi, thanks- was not working on it then- that's the problem, the photoset isn't displaying at all in the iframe- I tried adding `.photoset { height:initial };` to style.css but that didn't fix things

Comment: Hmm well it's working for me, and it's not showing in an iframe (although it was earlier today when I checked). http://imgur.com/a/j8JX6

Comment: Thanks- so it seems like that does get the image to display, which is great- but the image is severely cropped (click on the thumbnail to see the whole thing).  Any idea how I can avoid the cutoff?

Comment: I will add the start of an answer, I don't know for sure if it will solve your problem as I can't test it, but it should be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your photoset layout block to something like this (you may need to tweak this slightly):

```
{block:Photoset}
    <div class="content photoset">
        {block:Photos}
           <img src="{PhotoURL-500}"/>
        {/block:Photos}
        {block:Caption}
           <div class="description">{Caption}</div>
        {/block:Caption}
           <p><a href="{Permalink}" class="link"></a></p>
    </div>
{/block:Photoset}
```

Keep a backup of your current theme.

This should output the photoset in the normal html template (not iframe). From there it should be much easier to control the height  of the content, in fact by default it should just output the content and the height will be fixed automatically. But there might be other issues to investigate after this.